# Why do i get a "Post request fails. Cannot get predictions" error when calling gcloud AIP (unified) batch prediction?

Tags: gcloud, google-ai-platform

calling a batch prediction for a model deployed on AIP unified
results in an empty results file and a single error file with the following content:

```
('Post request fails. Cannot get predictions. Error: Unexpected response- {"predictions":[{"data":[{"715":{"0":1}}]}]}.', 1)
```

This is weird since the error message contains the correct output: `{"predictions":[{"data":[{"715":{"0":1}}]}]}`, which means that the prediction ran successfully and was the receiving end was able to read it,
the input is JSONL format and includes only a single instance for test purposes

Any idea?

Comment: Hmm.... I'm reading through the docs right now to try and help, and I'm noticing that the response it's giving you is missing a field deployedModelID. At least, according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints/predict#response-body) it should have this field... However reading through it's GO documentation it can be ommitted... My best guess is that the issue lies somewhere in the modelID you've declared. would you mind including an [mre] in your response?

Comment: My bad, I'm pretty sure the [go documentation I was reading](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/aiplatform/v1beta1) was the classic AIP.  So it looks like the modelID field is missing. Would still like the mre to be able to tell you why that's happening.